# When click on down arrow in search box displaying html data instaed of search found value

Tags: php, jquery

I am using a search box where when we enter the charaters it gets the data from database and displays the found data below text box like dropdown.For this i have used bootstap.Below is my code for that,

```
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
            name: 'typeahead',
            remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
            limit : 10
        });
```

search.php code:

```
<?php
$key=$_GET['key'];
        //$array = array();
        $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        $db=mysql_select_db("factlydb",$con);
        $query=mysql_query("select * from biodata where FIRST_NAME LIKE '%{$key}%' OR LAST_NAME LIKE '%{$key}%' OR CONSTITUENCY LIKE '%{$key}%'");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $ID=$row['ID'];
$array[] = "<span id='$ID'>".$row['FIRST_NAME']." ".$row['LAST_NAME']."</span>";
        }
        echo json_encode($array);

    ?>
```

its working fine to display the search found value, but when i use down arrow its displaying the html data like `<span id='1'>Sachin Tendulkar</span>` instead of displaying Sachin Tendulkar. If i remove span its working fine but, when click on that name i need to call ajax and send id as a parameter to php file and when click enter on keyboard also not working but click event is working. I have tried in different ways. Can any one please help me on this,thanks.

Comment: Just a comment: PHP's "mysql_" functions are deprecated. You should try at least "mysqli_" functions, or PDO statements.. It won't solve your issue, but it's a good practice.. Sorry i'm not helping with the real problem..

Comment: Thanks! for your suggestion. I am new to php. I will change my code.